# Why does summarize or mutate not work with group_by when I load `plyr` after `dplyr`?

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, r-faq

*Note:* The title of this question has been edited to make it the canonical question for issues when `plyr` functions mask their `dplyr` counterparts. The rest of the question remains unchanged.

---

Suppose I have the following data:

```
dfx <- data.frame(
  group = c(rep('A', 8), rep('B', 15), rep('C', 6)),
  sex = sample(c("M", "F"), size = 29, replace = TRUE),
  age = runif(n = 29, min = 18, max = 54)
)
```

With the good old `plyr` I can create a little table summarizing my data with the following code:

```
require(plyr)
ddply(dfx, .(group, sex), summarize,
      mean = round(mean(age), 2),
      sd = round(sd(age), 2))
```

The output look like this:

```
  group sex  mean    sd
1     A   F 49.68  5.68
2     A   M 32.21  6.27
3     B   F 31.87  9.80
4     B   M 37.54  9.73
5     C   F 40.61 15.21
6     C   M 36.33 11.33
```

I'm trying to move my code to `dplyr` and the `%>%` operator. My code takes DF then group it by group and sex and then summarise it. That is:

```
dfx %>% group_by(group, sex) %>% 
  summarise(mean = round(mean(age), 2), sd = round(sd(age), 2))
```

But my output is:

```
  mean   sd
1 35.56 9.92
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem here is that you are loading dplyr first and then plyr, so plyr's function `summarise` is masking dplyr's function `summarise`. When that happens you get this warning:

```
library(plyr)
    Loading required package: plyr
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
You have loaded plyr after dplyr - this is likely to cause problems.
If you need functions from both plyr and dplyr, please load plyr first, then dplyr:
library(plyr); library(dplyr)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Attaching package: ‘plyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

    arrange, desc, failwith, id, mutate, summarise, summarize
```

So in order for your code to work, either detach plyr `detach(package:plyr)` or restart R and load plyr first and then dplyr (or load only dplyr):

```
library(dplyr)
dfx %>% group_by(group, sex) %>% 
  summarise(mean = round(mean(age), 2), sd = round(sd(age), 2))
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
Groups: group

  group sex  mean    sd
1     A   F 41.51  8.24
2     A   M 32.23 11.85
3     B   F 38.79 11.93
4     B   M 31.00  7.92
5     C   F 24.97  7.46
6     C   M 36.17  9.11
```

Or you can explicitly call dplyr's summarise in your code, so the right function will be called no matter how you load the packages:

```
dfx %>% group_by(group, sex) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(mean = round(mean(age), 2), sd = round(sd(age), 2))
```

Comment: I don't understand why so few people notice that warning :/

Comment: @hadley `fortunes::fortune(9)`

Answer (score 4):

Your code is calling `plyr::summarise` instead of `dplyr::summarise` due to the order in which you have loaded "plyr" and "dplyr".

Demo:

```
library(dplyr) ## I'm guessing this is the order you loaded
library(plyr)
dfx %>% group_by(group, sex) %>% 
  summarise(mean = round(mean(age), 2), sd = round(sd(age), 2))
#    mean   sd
# 1 36.88 9.76
dfx %>% group_by(group, sex) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(mean = round(mean(age), 2), sd = round(sd(age), 2))
# Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
# Groups: group
# 
#   group sex  mean    sd
# 1     A   F 32.17  6.30
# 2     A   M 30.98  7.37
# 3     B   F 38.20  7.67
# 4     B   M 33.12 12.24
# 5     C   F 43.91 10.31
# 6     C   M 47.53  8.25
```