# dplyr: aggregating with group_by

Tags: r

I'm getting unexpected results when trying to sum by group using dplyr. Instead of getting the sum of sales for each person, I keep getting the sum of sales for everyone.  Here's an example:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(name = rep(c("John","Mary", "Lee"),3), 
                 year = rep(c(2014,2013,2012), each=3), 
                 sales = rep(c(10,20,30),3)
                )

df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(totals = sum(sales))
```

This should be so simple but I can't seem to get it to work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: detach the `plyr` package.

Comment: In the future, you 1. can do `library(plyr)` *before* the first occurence of `library(dplyr)` 2. can get around this by specifying `dplyr::summarise`

Comment: Did you notice the warning if you loaded `plyr` after `dplyr`? See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106146/using-dplyr-to-summarise-by-group).