# Finding proportions in Flights dataset in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to learn dplyr and I was using nywflights13 package. I was trying to find out proportions of flights from Origin(NYC(EWR,JFK)) to destination(Seattle)

The output I am expecting is,

```
Origin   n     Prop
JFK     2092     53
EWR     1831     47
```

I am able to do it in other ways. But I am trying to find using dplyr package. I tried the following without much success,

```
 library("nycflights13")

   flights %>% filter(dest=="SEA") %>% group_by(origin) %>% 
summarise(n=n(origin)) %>% mutate(Prop= n / sum(n))
```

But I am getting an error as `Error in n(origin) : unused argument (origin)`

Can anybody help me what correction I should do in this?

Comment: Error in n() : This function should not be called directly

Comment: I tried that already.. This is the error I am getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both `plyr` and `dplyr` are loaded, we could have masking of `summarise`, `mutate` etc.  It is better to use

```
  dplyr::summarise(n=n())
```

Using the full code,

```
  flights %>% 
    filter(dest=="SEA") %>%
    group_by(origin) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise (n = n()) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(freq = n / sum(n))
 # Source: local data frame [2 x 3]

 #  origin     n      freq
 #  (chr) (int)     (dbl)
 #1    EWR  1831 0.4667346
 #2    JFK  2092 0.5332654
```

Comment: flights %>% filter(dest=="SEA") %>% group_by(origin) %>% summarise (n = n()) %>% mutate(freq = n / sum(n))

When i use this, I get the following error,

Error in n() : This function should not be called directly

Comment: Try `dplyr::summarise(n=n())`

Comment: where should I use this?

Comment: @haimen This works for me.  As I mentioned, it must be a case of masking function by plyr::summarise if both libraries are loaded.

Comment: Yeah It works for me too.. not able to accept the answer now. Will do it in `10 mins.

Comment: I was just wondering what was the reason I was missing it.. Thanks a lot

Comment: @haimen  Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106146/why-does-summarise-on-grouped-data-result-in-only-overall-summary-in-dplyr)