# Get first and last values per group – dplyr group_by with last() and first()

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

The code below should group the data by year and then create two new columns with the first and last value of each year.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

d <- data.frame(
    group = rep(1:3, each = 3),
    year = rep(seq(2000,2002,1),3),
    value = sample(1:9, r = T))

d %>% 
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(
        first = dplyr::first(value),
        last = dplyr::last(value)
    )
```

However, it does not work as it should. The expected result would be

```
  group  year value first  last
  <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1     1  2000     3     3     4
2     1  2001     8     3     4
3     1  2002     4     3     4
4     2  2000     8     8     1
5     2  2001     9     8     1
6     2  2002     1     8     1
7     3  2000     5     5     5
8     3  2001     9     5     5
9     3  2002     5     5     5
```

Yet, I get this (it takes the first and the last value over the entire data frame, not just the groups):

```
  group  year value first  last
  <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1     1  2000     3     3     5
2     1  2001     8     3     5
3     1  2002     4     3     5
4     2  2000     8     3     5
5     2  2001     9     3     5
6     2  2002     1     3     5
7     3  2000     5     3     5
8     3  2001     9     3     5
9     3  2002     5     3     5
```

Comment: It works for me: I get a column with the first value by group and one with the last value by group.

Comment: Could you show the version of `dplyr`

Comment: Do you want `summarize` instead of mutate?

Comment: My guess is a [duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26106218/903061), that you are inadvertently using `plyr::mutate` instead of `dplyr::mutate`. However "*does not work as intended*" is so vague of a description that it's impossible to know...

Comment: thanks all! @Gregor that solved the issue! also, i've updated the question to be more precise wrt expected result vs. actual result.

Answer (score 48):

`dplyr::mutate()` did the trick

```
d %>% 
    group_by(group) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
        first = dplyr::first(value),
        last = dplyr::last(value)
    )
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also try by using summarise function within dpylr to get the first and last values of unique groups

```
 d %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
        summarise(first_value = first(na.omit(values)),
            last_value = last(na.omit(values))) %>% 
               left_join(d, ., by = 'group')
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, this is a "tidier" solution!  I had great trouble with using first() and last() within a mutate() on a tibble that was grouped on multiple variables, and couldn't figure out why the mutate call had silently failed to add more than one column (for the first_value).  Rather than continue to debug, I decided to take your suggestion and use summarise() instead.  I'm vaguely thinking that last() is somewhat hazardous to apply in a tibble with multiple levels of grouping, because NA can arise at any level in its lists of lists of lists (of lists of lists of ...).

Answer (score 11):

If you are from the future and `dplyr` has stopped supporting the `first` and `last` functions or want a future-proof solution, you can just index the columns like you would a list:

```
> d %>% 
        group_by(group) %>% 
        mutate(
                first = value[[1]], 
                last = value[[length(value)]]
        )
```

```
# A tibble: 9 × 5
# Groups:   group [3]
  group  year value first  last
  <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1     1  2000     3     3     4
2     1  2001     8     3     4
3     1  2002     4     3     4
4     2  2000     8     8     1
5     2  2001     9     8     1
6     2  2002     1     8     1
7     3  2000     5     5     5
8     3  2001     9     5     5
9     3  2002     5     5     5
```

Comment: Given the way Tidyverse handles sustainability regarding package functions, you’re probably right :)