# How can I add columns with the first and last occurence of a variable in an R dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe with in the format as seen in the bottom of my comment, but without the last 2 columns.

It is sorted by Name (chr), and Date(POSIXct). I want to add a 4. and 5. column, where the first and last occurence of each Name is listed, like this:

| ID | Name | Date | First | Last |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | A | 2010-10-01 | 2010-10-01 | 2010-12-31 |
| 4 | A | 2010-12-03 | 2010-10-01 | 2010-12-31 |
| 1 | A | 2010-12-31 | 2010-10-01 | 2010-12-31 |
| 2 | B | 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-01 |

How can I do that? There are NAs and NULLs in both Name and Date column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert the 'Date' to `Date` class, grouped by 'Name', get the `min` and `max` of 'Date' (if it is not already sorted or else in place of `min/max` use `first/last`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
     group_by(Name) %>%
     mutate(First = min(Date), Last = max(Date)) %>%
     ungroup
```

Comment: With this method, the values the First and Last columns are from the first and last row of the entire dataset, not that of the group. 
I tried to sort the dataset by an other column ('Type', not shown in my example above), and after this, I tried to run your code again. It seems that the group_by function doesn't sort the data, even when I left out the 'ungroup' line.
I also tried to factor the Name column, but still no success.

Comment: For anyone having the same problem: I loaded plyr before dplyr, and it masked the mutate function. 
Relevant questions: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654219/get-first-and-last-values-in-group-dplyr-group-by-with-last-and-first)
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106146/why-does-summarize-or-mutate-not-work-with-group-by-when-i-load-plyr-after-dp/26106218#26106218)

Comment: @xsw2yaqw1 if that is the case, you can do `dplyr::mutate(First = min(Date),..` to correct it

Comment: That is a common problem. I wonder why this was not corrected or changed the function name