# How to get the first values by group

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I would like to retrieve the first non-zero values from all groups.

**DataFrame**

```
Group  values Days
A      0      12 
A      0      15
A      30     18
A      60     20
B      0      2
B      15     10
B      16     20
B      20     30
C      0      5
C      30     10
C      70     15
```

Output

```
Group Values  Days
A     30      18
B     15      10
C     30      10
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get first and last values per group – dplyr group\_by with last() and first()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654219/get-first-and-last-values-per-group-dplyr-group-by-with-last-and-first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!values == 0, .SD[1], Group]
#    Group values Days
# 1:     A     30   18
# 2:     B     15   10
# 3:     C     30   10
```

Answer (score 3):

Two subset`'s.

```
df |> subset(values > 0) |> subset(!duplicated(Group)) 
#    Group values Days
# 3      A     30   18
# 6      B     15   10
# 10     C     30   10
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"C", "C", "C"), values = c(0L, 0L, 30L, 60L, 0L, 15L, 16L, 20L, 
0L, 30L, 70L), Days = c(12L, 15L, 18L, 20L, 2L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 
5L, 10L, 15L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could first `filter` the rows with values 0 and after that `slice` the first value `.by` you Group like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(values != 0) %>%
  slice(1, .by = Group)
#>   Group values Days
#> 1     A     30   18
#> 2     B     15   10
#> 3     C     30   10
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
> subset(df, ave(values != 0, Group, FUN = cumsum) == 1)
   Group values Days
3      A     30   18
6      B     15   10
10     C     30   10
```

or

```
> aggregate(. ~ Group, subset(df, values != 0), head, 1)
  Group values Days
1     A     30   18
2     B     15   10
3     C     30   10
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively we can try

```r
library(dplyr) 

df %>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate(val=cumall(lag(!values))) %>% 
filter(is.na(val)) %>% slice_tail(n=1) %>% select(-val)

# ouuput

# A tibble: 3 × 3
# Groups:   Group [3]
  Group values  Days
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         30    18
2 B         15    10
3 C         30    10
```