# Creating a variable by group in r

Tags: r

I have trying to calculate percentage of a row by group but i don't seem to get it.

**Data**

```
df = data.frame(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
            ID_name = c("AA", "AA", "BB", "BB", "CC", "CC", "DD", "DD", "DD"), 
            Volume = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 40L, 20L, 30L, 10L))
```

I want it to create a new column (Percentage) which will calculate Proportion of volume by ID

Ideal data will look like this (for all IDs but right now I am only showing for ID=1)

```
ID  ID_Name  Volume  Percentage
1    AA       10       0.33
1    AA       20       0.67
```

I tried this code but it doesn't seem to work

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(PercVol = Volume/sum(Volume))
```

Output of the code:

```
     ID     ID_name Volume    PercVol
     (int)  (fctr)  (int)     (dbl)
1     1      AA     10        0.03846154
2     1      AA     20        0.07692308
3     2      BB     30        0.11538462
4     2      BB     50        0.19230769
5     3      CC     50        0.19230769
6     3      CC     40        0.15384615
7     4      DD     20        0.07692308
8     4      DD     30        0.11538462
9     4      DD     10        0.03846154
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Did you load `plyr` after `dplyr` and ignore the printed warning? Try specifically using `dplyr::mutate`,  or look at `conflicts()` to see if `mutate` is listed.

Comment: Suggested duplicate (awaiting confirmation): [Why does summarize (or mutate) not work when I load `plyr` after `dplyr`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26106146/903061).

Comment: This will give it to you in a very rough format which you can clean up. No need for libraries. `aggregate(df$Volume, by=list(df$ID), prop.table)
`.... and now I'm noticing the part where your original code works fine. You just need to detach the conflicting packages (even just temporarily).

Comment: Thank you, both! It works both ways. The package was really the issue or rather the order of loading the packages. Thank!