# Correct use of the group_by and summarise() functions?

Tags: r, dplyr

I apologize for the low-level question, I am just starting out in programming.

I have the following tibble (which I know is not tidy) and I would like to compute the mean of the systolic pressure for each subject, using dplyr::group_by and dplyr::summarise():

```
bp_systolic2 <- tribble(
  ~ subject_id,  ~ time, ~ systolic,
  1,       1,        120,
  1,       2,        118,
  1,       3,        121,
  2,       1,        125,
  2,       2,        131,
  3,       1,        141
)
```

I have tried this:

```
group_by(bp_systolic2, subject_id) %>%
summarise(mean_systolic = mean(systolic))
```

However, this just returns a 1x1 tibble with the mean of the whole systolic column. How can I return a tibble (presumably 3x1) which contains the mean systolic for each subject?

Comment: I am getting 3 rows. Did you `library(dplyr)`? Or namespace everything with `dplyr::`

Comment: @dmi3kno I did; this is very weird. I am currently using Rstudio, I will try to check it in base R.

Comment: It works fine for me as well. It might be a good idea to clear your workspace and then try again.

Comment: Maybe: [Why does summarize or mutate not work with groups_by when I load `plyr` after `dplyr`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106146/why-does-summarize-or-mutate-not-work-with-groups-by-when-i-load-plyr-after-d)

Comment: Yup, using `plyr::summarise` gives you one row and I bet that is what is happening

Comment: @dmi3kno Hmm in base R I am getting 3 rows as well, but still not in R studio...

Comment: @dash2 Ah thank you, I substituted dplyr:summarise and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your usage is correct. This issue usually occurs when summarise from another package is loaded over dplyr. (for instance when you load plyr after dplyr). Can you try to use `dplyr::summarise` instead of `summarise`.