# Sum across categories and dates using r (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set that tracks daily revenue by id, category and date:

```
id       cat        date     daily_rev
111       A        3/09/19     $10
111       A        3/10/19     $15
111       A        3/11/19     $40
222       A        3/09/19     $100
222       A        3/10/19     $150
222       A        3/11/19     $50
333       B        3/09/19     $45
333       B        3/10/19     $10
333       B        3/11/19     $30
```

I want to manipulate the data to sum across all dates by category:

```
cat     tot_daily_rev
 A          $365
 B          $85
```

When I use this code:

`X <- data %>% 
  group_by(cat) %>%
  mutate(tot_daily_rev = sum(daily_rev))`

I get a data frame that has a tot_daily_rev column that is a sum of every row in the data set:

```
id       cat        date     daily_rev     tot_daily_rev
111       A        3/09/19     $10              $450
111       A        3/10/19     $15              $450
111       A        3/11/19     $40              $450
222       A        3/09/19     $100             $450
222       A        3/10/19     $150             $450
222       A        3/11/19     $50              $450
333       B        3/09/19     $45              $450
333       B        3/10/19     $10              $450
333       B        3/11/19     $30              $450
```

I've already referenced this post: [How to sum a variable by group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group),  but it does not solve my issue.

--

**Update**

[Why does summarize or mutate not work with group_by when I load `plyr` after `dplyr`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106146/why-does-summarize-or-mutate-not-work-with-group-by-when-i-load-plyr-after-dp) addresses the same issue! I was completely unaware that this was an issue of functions/libraries, so I didn't think to search for why summarize and mutate were not behaving as I expected.

Comment: Use `summarize()` instead of `mutate()`.

Comment: Is there any chance that you've also loaded the `plyr` package? If you have, its version of `mutate` does not respect the groups created by `group_by`. Specify `dplyr::mutate` or `dplyr::summarize` in your code to be sure the right version is being used.

Comment: thanks @jdobres, i forgot to mention that i've tried `summarize()`. when i use `summarize()`, it returns a 1 x 1 data frame with the value $450.

Comment: Again, be sure that you're calling dplyr's version of `mutate` with `dplyr::mutate`.

Comment: @jdobres thank you! i didn't know that about the difference between plyr::mutate and dplyr::mutate. completely solved my issue!!

Answer (score 0):

Its not `mutate` when you're using `group_by`. After you've used `group_by` its now a `group_by` object, so you have to use `summarize`

```
X <- data %>% 
  group_by(cat) %>%
  summarize(tot_daily_rev = sum(daily_rev))
```

Comment: This is incorrect, `summarize` is  used if you want one row per group. `mutate` is used if you want to keep the original number of rows. In both cases, operations will still be done "by group". (It does look like OP wants `summarize`, not `mutate`, but there is a time and place for `mutate`, and it still works just fine after `group_by`).