# Generate self reference key within the table using R mutate in a dataframe

Tags: r, dictionary, purrr, dplyr

I have an input table with 3 columns (Person_Id, Visit_Id (unique Id for each visit and each person)  and Purpose) as shown below. I would like to generate another new column which provides the immediate preceding visit of the person (ex: if person has visited hospital with Visit Id = 2, then I would like to have another column called "Preceding_visit_Id" which will be 1 (ex:2, if visit id = 5, preceding visit id will be 4). Is there a way to do this in a elegant manner using mutate function?

Input Table

> [image]

Output Table

> [image]
>   As you can see that 'Preceding_visit_id' column refers the previous visit of the person which is defined using visit_id column

Please note that this is a transformation for one of the columns in a huge program, so anything elegant would be helpful.

Dput command output is here

```
structure(list(Person_Id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3), Visit_Id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14), Purpose = c("checkup", "checkup", "checkup", "checkup", 
"checkup", "checkup", "checkup", "checkup", "checkup", "checkup", 
"checkup", "checkup", "checkup", "checkup"), Preceding_visit_id = c(NA, 
1, 2, 3, 4, NA, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, NA, 12, 12)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), spec = 
structure(list(
 cols = list(Person_Id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Visit_Id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Purpose = structure(list(), class = 
 c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Preceding_visit_id = structure(list(), class = 
 c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))'''
```

Comment: `df %>% group_by(Person_Id) %>% mutate(Preceding_visit_id = lag(Visit_Id, 1))`

Comment: @JasonAizkalns, Can you let me know how can this be done when the visit_id is a sequence number? I have updated the screenshot above for your reference? Can you please help me?

Comment: did you try running that code? Where are you getting stuck? Please see [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/2572423) so that others can help.

Comment: I already ran that and found out that the way I provided the sample data was incorrect. For example, The code generated the preceding_visit_id as 5 for person_id = 2 when his first visit was at (visit_id = 6). Though it was grouped, since we have used lag, it picks the last observation (visit_id) of the previous group (person before the current patient)

Comment: Pictures of data are impossible to test on. Please update your question sharing data with `dput()` instead.

Comment: Also please clarify what isn't working with Jason's suggestion, it looks perfect. If mutate seems to be ignoring your grouping, then make sure you haven't loaded `plyr` after `dplyr` and ignored the warning that prints. [See this R-FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26106146/903061).

Comment: Hello! Please find the dput command output updated above

Comment: This is the order in which I have the packages  library(data.table)
library(purrr)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)                # importing necessary packages
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

Comment: Your `person_id` fields don't match in your examples.

Comment: Can you please help me with this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56801904/how-to-override-coerce-error-and-create-a-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Person_Id` fields in your examples don't match.

I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but from your `dput()` I have created a file that removes the last column:

```
df_input <- df_output %>% 
  select(-Preceding_visit_id)
```

Then done this:

```
df_input %>% 
  group_by(Person_Id) %>% 
  mutate(Preceding_visit_id = lag(Visit_Id))
```

And the output is this:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 4
# Groups:   Person_Id [3]
   Person_Id Visit_Id Purpose Preceding_visit_id
       <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>                <dbl>
 1         1        1 checkup                 NA
 2         1        2 checkup                  1
 3         1        3 checkup                  2
 4         1        4 checkup                  3
 5         1        5 checkup                  4
 6         2        6 checkup                 NA
 7         2        7 checkup                  6
 8         2        8 checkup                  7
 9         2        9 checkup                  8
10         2       10 checkup                  9
11         2       11 checkup                 10
12         3       12 checkup                 NA
13         3       13 checkup                 12
14         3       14 checkup                 13
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error message when I use the above suggestion 9in my dataset. The message reads as "Column `preceding_visit_id
` must be length 16 (the group size) or one, not 256612" . Here 256612 is my dataset size and number of unique person Id (groups) are more than 16 as well. Can you Please help as t what is wring here?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Is the dataset all in the same format?

Comment: Yes, the dataset is in the same format .Can you look into this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55395940/mutate-new-variable-on-one-dataframe-by-deriving-value-from-another-dataframe.

Comment: Did the `ungroup()` answer in your other post work? It would have been grouped in the input. Sometimes that could be the issue.

Comment: Can you please help me understand better? For ex: if my dataframe has categorical data, can it be called as grouped? There have been cases where I followed the same approach for other dataframe for similar 'Code' columns and it worked but for this dataframe it is throwing this error

Comment: I mean this bit `group_by(Person_Id) %>% `. I wouldn't be able to tell without looking at it. Is there a way of you making the other dataset not confidential? Change some of the data or remove some columns perhaps?