# Mutate new variable on one dataframe by deriving value from another dataframe - Incompatible Issue

Tags: r, dataframe, dictionary, dplyr

I am using mutate to create a new column in dataframe `A` by fetching values from a dataframe `B`.

I already tried using the below code but it started throwing an error. 
Not sure whether I am making any mistakes here. Please find the code below.

Apologies, that I can't share data as it is confidential. However the objective is simple and am sure I am making a blunder somewhere. Can you correct me?

Here, `dfm` is the dataframe which was already created, from which I will use the 'Code' column values for new dataframe(DF) which was also created but without the 'Visit_concept_id' column.

```
dfm - Old dataframe with 'Code' column of length 256612
DF %>%
   mutate(visit_concept_id = as.integer(as.character(dfm$Code)))
```

I expect the 'Code' column values from dfm dataframe to be populated in visit_concept_id column of new dataframe(DF) but I am receiving error as shown below. Please help. Not sure how it was working earlier and not now.

> Error: Column `visit_concept_id` must be length 16 (the group size) or one, not 256612

str(df) is given below

> Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   256612 obs. of  17 variables:
>    $ visit_occurrence_id          : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
>    $ person_id                    : int  127 12097 348097 4324235 214214 4213 41412 634643 241245 3255 ...
>    $ visit_concept_id             : int  32036 32036 32036 32036 32036 32036 32036 32036 32036 32036 ...
>    $ visit_start_date             : Date, format: "2169-06-08" "2169-06-08" "2169-06-08" ...
>    $ visit_start_datetime         : POSIXct, format: "2169-06-08 09:40:00" "2169-06-08 09:41:00" "2169-06-08 09:42:00" ...
>    $ visit_end_date               : Date, format: "2169-06-08" "2169-06-08" "2169-06-08" ...
>    $ visit_end_datetime           : POSIXct, format: "2169-06-08 09:40:00" "2169-06-08 09:41:00" "2169-06-08 09:42:00" ...
>    $ visit_type_concept_id        : int  44818518 44818518 44818518 44818518 44818518 44818518 44818518 44818518 44818518 44818518 ...
>    $ provider_id                  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
>    $ care_site_id                 : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
>    $ visit_source_value           : chr  "Outpatient" "Outpatient" "Outpatient" "Outpatient" ...
>    $ visit_source_concept_id      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
>    $ admitting_source_concept_id  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
>    $ admitting_source_value       : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
>    $ discharge_to_concept_id      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
>    $ discharge_to_source_value    : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
>    $ preceding_visit_occurrence_id: int  0 1 2 3 4 0 6 7 8 9 ...

Comment: What type of field is the `Code` field? Is it a number that is coded as an integer? Does this work? `DF <- dtm %>%
   mutate(visit_concept_id = as.integer(as.character(Code)))`

Comment: Code field has 4 distinct values, for example, 1234, 4567, 2345, 6543. Hence it was a factor datatype. In my new column, I wanted it to be integer and so I converted it

Comment: Sorry, for the code above, I meant `(DF <- dtm %>% mutate(visit_concept_id = as.integer((Code)))` - without the .`as.character`. I don't know if it will make any difference though.

Comment: Another thing is, is there a way to assign value to a new column as shown above but retain the order. I mean Code column when assigned to visit_concept_id, the values are shuffled. Is there a way to prevent that? Other than using merge/join, is there anyway that I can do this elegantly through mutate?

Comment: You can `arrange` but it is hard to tell without seeing your dataset. Perhaps it is better to keept it as a factor. Can you provide the first few lines of the output of `str(dtm)` (deleting anything confidential)? This will give me an idea of the first problem, not necessarily the second problem.

Comment: please find the details updated above

Comment: Sorry, I thought it might have been something in the format. If you want a good response, it would be good provide a `dput` of the data, perhaps `dput(head(dtm))` would be more appropriate. Actually, has the question been resolved? You have marked it as resolved.

Comment: Sure, I have asked for permission. Is there any difference between the below two statements in assigning a value  1) "" preceding_visit_occurrence_id = lag(.$visit_occurrence_id,1)""  2) ""preceding_visit_occurrence_id = lag(visit_occurrence_id,1)"" Please note that these two statements are under the mutate section

Comment: Hard to tell without the context, but you shouldn't need the `.$` if you are using the `%>%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message your data is grouped.
Try this

```
DF %>% ungroup() %>%
   mutate(visit_concept_id = as.integer(as.character(dfm$Code)))
```

Comment: Actually, I didn't use any group by function at all. There is another dataframe called DF in which I would like to add this column (Code). How does R interprets it as 'grouped'? Can you please help me understand?

Comment: can help me with this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63370682/unable-to-use-select-map-and-what-does-indicate-in-r