# Averages of a Gather() Values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset I initially manipulate with the gather() function. I am now attempting to create averages of groups in the gathered data. I am having issues understanding the best way to create averages of the data provided here. My hope is to create an average associated to each group. Here I am averaging scores for 'observers'.

EDIT: **I need an average for each observer over all dates of observation.**

EDIT-2: Each observer has any number of individuals they will be assessing. If I use group_by(observer) the average will be over all observations total, not an average for the observer.

EDIT-3: I am hoping to see averages of each observation dates 'fidelity score'. If I have 3 scores (90,100,120), I would like to see an average of these values attributed to the observer, but still be able to display the scores over time. The output I am hoping for would be:

[image]

**Important Note: My fidelity scores are all out of 129 possible points**

**EDIT-4: I would like to average observer scores over the count to observations(date_of_observation)**

Here is the function I am using to create my averages.

```
LPLC_Group %>%
  group_by(observer,date_of_observation)%>%
  summarize(fidelity_score = sum(value,na.rm=TRUE),
        average_fidelity = round(mean(fidelity_score,na.rm=TRUE),2))
```

The following dput is related to the output of the function above. **I cannot post my full dataset.** The output of this function should be enough to work with.

dput output:

```
structure(list(observer = c("Cristianne", "Cristianne", "Cristianne", 
"Deb", "Deb", "Deb", "Lori", "Lori", "Lori", "Pauline", "Pauline", 
"Pauline"), date_of_observation = c("6/24/19", "7/24/19", "8/24/19", 
"6/24/19", "7/24/19", "8/24/19", "6/24/19", "7/24/19", "8/24/19", 
"6/24/19", "7/24/19", "8/24/19"), fidelity_score = c(100L, 87L, 
95L, 89L, 106L, 98L, 85L, 104L, 102L, 94L, 85L, 113L), average_fidelity = c(100, 
87, 95, 89, 106, 98, 85, 104, 102, 94, 85, 113)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(
    observer = c("Cristianne", "Deb", "Lori", "Pauline"), .rows = list(
        1:3, 4:6, 7:9, 10:12)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: What is your expected

Comment: I need an average for each observer over all dates of observation.

Comment: You want an average for each observer, so use `group_by(observer)`

Comment: The date of observation is key for the visualization I am making. group_by works, but then the time value is gone. Thoughts? @Gregor

Comment: Please show the output you want corresponding to your sample inputs. The statement *"If I use `group_by(observer)` the average will be over all observations total, not an average for the observer"* seems completely wrong. If you use `group_by(observer)`, you will get one row per observer, with the average value for all observations for each observer---aka "an average for the observer". This seems to be what you describe, but not what you want. So please show what you want as the description is failing.

Comment: Added some clarification @Gregor

Comment: "*but still be able to display the scores over time*", ah, new key information. Use `group_by(observer)`, but use `mutate()` instead of `summarize()`. `mutate` adds columns to existing data, `summarize` summarizes the data to 1-row-per-group.

Comment: @Gregor the alteration you have recommended, does not alter the output I am seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
LPLC_Group %>%
  group_by(observer) %>%
  mutate(average_fidelity = mean(fidelity_score))
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   observer [4]
   observer   date_of_observation fidelity_score average_fidelity
   <chr>      <chr>                        <int>            <dbl>
 1 Cristianne 6/24/19                        100             94  
 2 Cristianne 7/24/19                         87             94  
 3 Cristianne 8/24/19                         95             94  
 4 Deb        6/24/19                         89             97.7
 5 Deb        7/24/19                        106             97.7
 6 Deb        8/24/19                         98             97.7
 7 Lori       6/24/19                         85             97  
 8 Lori       7/24/19                        104             97  
 9 Lori       8/24/19                        102             97  
10 Pauline    6/24/19                         94             97.3
11 Pauline    7/24/19                         85             97.3
12 Pauline    8/24/19                        113             97.3
```

If the output you get does not match mine for this input, then you have probably succumbed to the mistake of [Loading `plyr` after `dplyr` and ignoring the warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26106146/903061). I would suggest restarting R and being careful to load `plyr` **before** `dplyr` (if at all).

Comment: Thank you for the help, this will help me immensely.