# Function summarise in dplyr don't work. Factors are not grouped

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, pipe, summarize

I'm trying to use the dplyr function summarise together with group by to get the sum of my factors. This is my dataset:

```
brand = c("Mercedes","Mercedes","Mercedes","Mercedes","Mercedes",
          "Mercedes","Mercedes","Mercedes","Mercedes","BMW",
          "BMW","BMW","BMW","BMW","BMW","BMW","BMW","BMW")
model = c("SL_class", "SL_class", "SL_class", "A_class", 
          "A_class", "A_class", "E_class", "E_class", 
          "E_class", "4 Series", "4 Series", "4 Series", 
          "X1", "X1", "X1", "Z4", "Z4", "Z4")
variable = c(5,6,7,12,13,14,1,2,3,7,8,9,22,24,25,11,12,14)


data = data.frame(brand, model, variable)
data

data$brand <- factor(data$brand)
data$model <- factor(data$model)
```

But if I try to get the sum of `variables` for each level of `brand` I do get only a value (see below). Why do I lose the grouping?

```
data %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(brand) %>% 
  summarise(SUM = sum(variable))

  SUM
1 195
```

This is instead the result that I would like to get:

```
aggregate(data$variable, by = list(data$brand), 
          FUN =sum)

Group.1   x
1      BMW 132
2 Mercedes  63
```

Can someone help me to get this working in dplyr?

Comment: What if you use `dplyr::summarise()`. Do you have other packages loaded that also define a `summarise()` function? I can't replicate your problem. I get two rows when I copy/paste your code. Did you call `library(dplyr)` to load the library?

Comment: Maybe: [Why does summarize or mutate not work with group_by when I load `plyr` after `dplyr`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106146/why-does-summarize-or-mutate-not-work-with-group-by-when-i-load-plyr-after-dp)

Comment: It works if you use `library(dplyr)` instead of `dplyr::group_by(brand)`

Comment: Thank you for you help. I've solved it. It was the package Rmisc that was loading plyr after dplyr. If I load the package plyr first, it works