# summerarize dplyr only gives one row (not plyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, summarize

when I try to summeraize my data I get some strange results. But using group_by and than summeraize gives me only one observation, even though I have more different groups. Adding an Argument to group_by only gives one more Variable in the result.
However, like other post suggest (e.g. [Why does summarize or mutate not work with group_by when I load `plyr` after `dplyr`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106146/why-does-summarize-or-mutate-not-work-with-group-by-when-i-load-plyr-after-dp)) it could be plyr. But actually I didn't  load plyr and in my code I directly refer to dplyr. How to I get my expected result (one value each group)?
In the following my dput of my 1) code, 2) my original tabel: comb_extract_all and 3) my resulting table.

```
comb_extract_all_agg <- comb_extract_all %>% dplyr::group_by("SurveyId", "hhid", "CLUSTER") %>% 
                                  dplyr::summarize(hc70 =mean(hc70, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
                                    ungroup()
          
dput(comb_extract_all[1:10,1:10])
structure(list(hhid = c("        1 27", "        1 27", "        1 27", 
"        1 27", "        1 67", "        1 67", "        1 67", 
"        1 67", "        1 67", "        1225"), hv001 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), hv002 = c(27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 225L), hv005 = c(1707326L, 1707326L, 
1707326L, 1707326L, 1707326L, 1707326L, 1707326L, 1707326L, 1707326L, 
1707326L), hv007 = c(2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 
2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L), hv021 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), hv023 = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), labels = structure(1:23, names = c("tigray urban", 
"tigray rural", "affar urban", "affar rural", "amhara urban", 
"amhara rural", "oromiya urban", "oromiya rural", "somali urban", 
"somali rural", "benishangul-gumuz urban", "benishangul-gumuz rural", 
"s.n.n.p. urban", "s.n.n.p. rural", "gambela urban", "gambela rural", 
"harari urban", "harari rural", "addis ababa", "dire dawa urban", 
"dire dawa rural", "somali oversample urban", "somali oversample rural"
)), label = "Stratification used in sample design", class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "integer")), hv024 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), labels = c(tigray = 1L, affar = 2L, 
amhara = 3L, oromiya = 4L, somali = 5L, `benishangul-gumuz` = 6L, 
snnp = 7L, gambela = 12L, harari = 13L, `addis ababa` = 14L, 
`dire dawa` = 15L), label = "Region", class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "integer")), hv025 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), labels = structure(1:2, names = c("urban", 
"rural")), label = "Type of place of residence", class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "integer")), hc70 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), labels = c(`height out of plausible limits` = 9996, 
`age in days out of plausible limits` = 9997, `flagged cases` = 9998, 
missing = 9999), label = "Height/Age standard deviation (new WHO)", class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double"))), row.names = c("ETPR61FL.1", "ETPR61FL.2", 
"ETPR61FL.3", "ETPR61FL.4", "ETPR61FL.5", "ETPR61FL.6", "ETPR61FL.7", 
"ETPR61FL.8", "ETPR61FL.9", "ETPR61FL.10"), class = "data.frame")


dput(comb_extract_all_agg)
structure(list(`"SurveyId"` = "SurveyId", `"hhid"` = "hhid", 
    `"CLUSTER"` = "CLUSTER", hc70 = 683.255964376358), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Edit for comment:

```
    comb_extract_all |> select(SurveyId, CLUSTER, hhid, hc70) |> slice_sample(n = 5) |> dput()
structure(list(SurveyId = c("ET2016DHS", "ET2016DHS", "ET2019DHS", 
"ZW2010DHS", "ET2005DHS"), CLUSTER = structure(c(561L, 211L, 
143L, 166L, 241L), label = "Cluster number"), hhid = structure(c("     561  51", 
"     211 301", "    01430032", "      166 25", "      241246"
), label = "Case Identification"), hc70 = structure(c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 619), labels = c(`height out of plausible limits` = 9996, 
`age in days out of plausible limits` = 9997, `flagged cases` = 9998, 
missing = 9999), label = "Height/Age standard deviation (new WHO)", class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double"))), row.names = c("ETPR71FL.64958", "ETPR71FL.24246", 
"ETPR81FL.19619", "ZWPR62FL.17019", "147379"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Make sure all the variables you use are in your dataset. From your above data, there is no `SurveyId` or `CLUSTER` columns in the data you're trying to group by, and only one value of `hhid` across all rows, so `summarize` is giving one output row as a mean of all those just as expected. It may be that your sample dataset is too truncated to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Sorry, for that non clear dput: but my DF is to big to give an hole one. I added one, where you can see available SurveyId and Cluster

Comment: Unfortunately your new dataset is only one row, which means summarising still wont work! Try doing `comb_extract_all |> select(SurveyId, CLUSTER, hhid, hc70) |> slice_sample(n = 1) |> dput()` and pasting that to get a small data sample with all the necessary columns. Ideally, try your code on your sample before you post that too to make sure problem still persists for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst we're figuring out testable data, try not having the `group_by` variables in quotes. Produces three rows from your sample data (all `NA`s from your selected column):

```r
library(tidyverse)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "ETPR61FL.3", "ETPR61FL.4", "ETPR61FL.5", "ETPR61FL.6", "ETPR61FL.7", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "ETPR61FL.8", "ETPR61FL.9", "ETPR61FL.10"), class = "data.frame")
comb_extract_all %>% group_by(hhid) %>% 
  summarize(hc70 =mean(hc70, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   hhid            hc70
#>   <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 "        1 27"   NaN
#> 2 "        1 67"   NaN
#> 3 "        1225"   NaN
```

Comment: Ok dear Andy, that was a really stupid mistake of mine! Thanks for your convinient help!!

Comment: Glad it helped! easy mistake to make!

Answer (score -1):

The reason for this is that the plyr package also contains a function that is called summarize. Since we have loaded the plyr package after the dplyr package, the R programming language automatically used the plyr version of the function.

Comment: That would be quite strange for me since I did't load the plyr package and I directly adress dplyr package (by dplyr::) in my function, but if you still have an Idea how would be great

Comment: The OP only mentions package `plyr` to say that that's not it. This answer is wrong since the beginning of the question.