# ggplot and summarise not giving statistic per groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

Aim create bar chart where xaxis=day, yaxis=mass and fill=group

I have used pivot wider to get the data into a usable format. However I am stuck on how to summarise the data for inputing it into the bar chart - when i try and use summarise i get one summary statistic despite grouping by day and group

```
study_id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
group <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2)
mass_day1 <-c(NA,2,NA,3,NA,1)
mass_day2 <- c(15,15,15,15,NA,15)
mass_day3 <-c(3,3,3,3,3,3)
mass_day4 <- c(4,4,4,NA,4,4)

drink_df  <- data.frame(study_id,group,mass_day4,mass_day3,mass_day2,mass_day1) 

drink_dfa <- drink_df %>%   
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("mass"),       
               names_to = c(".value", "day"),    
               names_pattern = '(.*)_(.*)',
               values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(day,group) %>% summarise(
  mass = mean(mass), na.rm = TRUE) %>% ungroup()
  
plot <- ggplot(drink_dfa, aes(x = day, y = mass, fill = group)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), na.rm = FALSE)
```

Comment: Your `group` is numeric, so the fill is a continuous color scale. You probably want `group=factor(1,2,1,2,1,2)`.

Comment: Maybe try `dplyr::summarize`. Your code works for me. I see `drink_dfa` is a tibble with 7 rows and 4 columns. Do you have other packages like `plyr` loaded as well?

Comment: @James_D, correction, `factor(c(1,2,1,2,1,2))`, without the `c(..)` vector it returns a length-1 `NA` factor.

Comment: GJW, if you're also using `plyr`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/26106146/3358272 to see why you should either load `plyr` _before_ `dplyr` or force which function you intend by using `dplyr::summarize` (instead of R inferring `plyr::summarize`, a different function).

Comment: Thank you. 
dplyr::summarize solved the issue - recently started using another package that loaded plyr