# R - how to identify non-consecutive numeric values by group

Tags: r

I have a long dataset in which different subjects (identified with a `subj_id`) have attended to different stimuli identified by a consecutive variable `Trial_Nr`. I would like to identify the subjects in which the `Trial_Nr` sequence was disrupted, and where the disruption came about.

Here's a MWE:

```
df <- structure(list(Crowdsourcing_SubjId = c("5e42fc295135b5000cd20d0b", 
"5e42fc295135b5000cd20d0b", "5e42fc295135b5000cd20d0b", "5e42fc295135b5000cd20d0b", 
"5e42fc295135b5000cd20d0b", "5e42fc295135b5000cd20d0b", "63bd9ac0dc52225142c5b1d4", 
"63bd9ac0dc52225142c5b1d4", "63bd9ac0dc52225142c5b1d4", "63bd9ac0dc52225142c5b1d4"
), Trial_Nr = c(1:6, 1, 2, 5, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have found some other posts using `diff()`, but for some reason I am not able to make it work by group:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
group_by(Crowsourcing_SubjId) %>%
summarise(flag = diff(Trial_Nr))
```

Doing the above will just give me the row-wise difference for all subjects, without grouping, and without anyway to identify where the disruption occurs.

Here's the output I would like to get:

```
Crowdsourcing_SubjId      flag  disruption
5e42fc295135b5000cd20d0b  1     NA
63bd9ac0dc52225142c5b1d4  3     2
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Comment: You need to check if the difference equals 1 and you need to pad with one `TRUE` value in the beginning for each group.

Comment: If you use `summarise()` and your output is not grouped, then likely you are inadvertently using `plyr::summarise()` when you need `dplyr::summarise()`. See [this FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26106146/903061) for more explanation and solutions - the quick fix is to specify `dplyr::summarise()` with the two-colon notation.

Comment: @Rolad how do I do that?

Comment: @GregorThomas I did that, and the output is the same.

Comment: @Maël just added what I am hoping to get!

Comment: Your sample data is malformed - did you use `dput()` and edit it? There should be one `)` after `class = "data.frame"`, not two (and one more `)` before it)

Comment: @GregorThomas oops! fixed!

Comment: Also `row.names` are required for a data frame. Please test your sample data and make sure it creates a data frame before posting it.

Comment: And could you explain the meaning of `flag` and `disruption` in your desired output?

Comment: `flag` tells the difference between two values (5-2=3), `disruption` tells the location of the numerical disruption (i.e., the second term of the difference, in this case 2). Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, `flag` seems like a strange name for that (a flag is usually a binary or TRUE/FALSE variable), but with explanation it now makes sense.

Comment: If there are multiple disruptions within a group, do you want multiple rows for that group in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data that works to create a data frame, not a `list`:

```
df <- data.frame(Crowdsourcing_SubjId = c("5e42fc295135b5000cd20d0b", 
"5e42fc295135b5000cd20d0b", "5e42fc295135b5000cd20d0b", "5e42fc295135b5000cd20d0b", 
"5e42fc295135b5000cd20d0b", "5e42fc295135b5000cd20d0b", "63bd9ac0dc52225142c5b1d4", 
"63bd9ac0dc52225142c5b1d4", "63bd9ac0dc52225142c5b1d4", "63bd9ac0dc52225142c5b1d4"
), Trial_Nr = c(1:6, 1, 2, 5, 6))
```

This defines `flag` as the biggest difference between consecutive values by group, and `disruption` as the location of the **first** time the consecutive difference is greater than 1 by group.

```
library(dplyr)
df |>
  group_by(Crowdsourcing_SubjId) |>
  summarise(
    flag = max(diff(Trial_Nr)),
    disruption = match(TRUE, c(diff(Trial_Nr), 1) > 1)
  )
# # A tibble: 2 × 3
#   Crowdsourcing_SubjId      flag disruption
#   <chr>                    <dbl>      <int>
# 1 5e42fc295135b5000cd20d0b     1         NA
# 2 63bd9ac0dc52225142c5b1d4     3          2
```

Comment: I just saw your earlier comment. I assume this will only cover the first disruption within the same subject, right?

Comment: Yes, as I said *"This defines `flag` as the biggest difference between consecutive values by group, and `disruption` as the location of the **first** time the consecutive difference is greater than 1 by group."*

Comment: Thanks!!! What if I would like to record any potential disruption within the same subject?

Comment: You should ask a new question with sample data and desired output that illustrates that.

Comment: But basically you'll want to use `mutate` not summarize and add columns to your oiriginal data with the difference and location, and then `filter` to discard any rows that have the expected difference of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `diff` is a good start but you have to go a bit further. What you need is that consecutive lines in a group be separated by 1. So you need to compare the result of diffing with 1.

Using `data.table` package here is a partial solution.

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(df)

# compute pairwise difference between consecutive lines in a group
df[, by=Crowdsourcing_SubjId, flag := c(diff(Trial_Nr), 1)]

# select disruption size and position, added count to keep no disruption case
df[, by=Crowdsourcing_SubjId, .(
  count = sum(flag!=1),
  flag = flag[flag!=1], 
  disruption = which(flag!=1)
)]
```

Here is the result

```
       Crowdsourcing_SubjId count  flag disruption
                     <char> <int> <num>      <int>
1: 5e42fc295135b5000cd20d0b     0    NA         NA
2: 63bd9ac0dc52225142c5b1d4     1     3          2
```

Small difference with what you expect. When there are no disruption  returned flag will be `NA` instead of `1`.

Comment: Thanks! I am not familiar with the `data.table` package. Do you have at all an alternative solution using `tidyverse`?

Comment: I'm not very keen on dplyr but you can maybe start by a `mutate` to compute the flag (diff(x)!=1) and then summarize it

Comment: @gregor has the answer :-) Clever use of max and match to point and locate values

Comment: Updated my answer for the records using data.table